# C++: Error while allocating memory for a two dimensional array using functions

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I am trying to understand passing by reference and passing by value. In this program I have a two dimensional array which is declared in main and whose size is allocated in a function. In the allocate2DArrayRef() function, I obtain the two sizes and dynamically allocate and initialize the array Array2D.

Now I am trying to understand how to do the same by pointers. I have written another function  allocate2DArrayPtr() in where I pass a pointer to the two dimensional array, get the value of the sizes - sizeX and sizeY and then allocate the memory to the variable secArray2D.

When I run the program it hangs when I try to print out secArray2D. I am assuming this implies that the function allocate2DArrayPtr() has not been successful in dynamically allocating memory to the array secArray2D.

My final goal is to write a program which has a function that dynamically allocated memory and initializes multiple arrays of various dimensions which are read from an input file. I know I can expand on passing by reference function allocate2DArrayRef() to achieve my goal. But I am curious to learn why my function allocate2DArrayPtr() is not working as I want to be clear on how to pass by pointers also. I do know how to change allocate2DArrayPtr() to return a pointer but I would like to pass the array as a parameter.

I am running the program on windows 7 using Codeblocks 13.12 IDE.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void allocate2DArrayRef(int **&, int &, int &);
void allocate2DArrayPtr(int ***, int *, int *);

int main()
{
   int sizeX, sizeY;
   int **Array2D;
   allocate2DArrayRef(Array2D, sizeX, sizeY);
   for(int i=0; i< sizeX; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j< sizeY; j++)
      {
         cout << "Array2D[" << i << "][" << j << "]:" << Array2D[i][j] <<     endl;
      }
   }
   cout << endl << endl;
   int **secArray2D;
   allocate2DArrayPtr(&secArray2D, &sizeX, &sizeY);

   for(int i=0; i<sizeX; i++)
   {
      for(int j=0; j<sizeY; j++)
      {
         cout << "secArray2D[" << i << "][" << j << "]:" << secArray2D[i][j] << endl;
      }
   }

   return 0;
}

void allocate2DArrayRef(int **&locArray, int& indexFirst, int& indexSecond)
{
    indexFirst = 4;
    indexSecond = 5;
    locArray = new int*[indexFirst];
    for(int i=0; i<indexFirst ; i++)
    { 
        locArray[i] = new int[indexSecond];
        for(int j=0; j<indexSecond; j++)
        {
            locArray[i][j] = i*j;
        }
    }
}

void allocate2DArrayPtr(int ***locArray, int *indexFirst, int *indexSecond)
{
   *indexFirst = 2;
   *indexSecond = 3;
    int **temp = *locArray;
    temp = new int*[*indexFirst];
    for(int i=0; i<(*indexFirst) ; i++)
    {
       temp[i] = new int[*indexSecond];
       for(int j=0; j<(*indexSecond); j++)
       {
           temp[i][j] = i+j;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time and effort and use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: I am learning C++ step by step. From my searches online I have gleaned that STL can solve a lot of memory issues. But I still haven't learned STL and would like to make sure I understand pointers clearly before jumping ahead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason `allocate2DArrayPtr` does not work is you never set `locArray` to point to the array you create in the function.  This means when you return from the function `secArray2D` still is uninitialized.

Adding

```
*locArray = temp;
```

To the end of `allocate2DArrayPtr` will fix the problem.

Comment: No problem.  Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can reference your to temp like this:

```
int **&temp = *locArray;
```